# iOS: Setup of GeoFence via Remote Notification seems not to work

Tags: ios, notifications, core-location, geofencing, remote-notifications

for a PoC I have to test the following requirement. The client wants to send out remote notifications, which hold data for geofences within the notification. *I do not mean "normal" notifcations, instead I mean "silent" notifications. The user will not notice that he received a notification. Only the app receives data from this notification.*

So far so good: I have completed a test app, which does exactly what the client wants, i.e.

- I have a working app, which sets up some geofences during app start.
- Those fences work perfectly, all required background permissions are set correct.
- I can receive *(silent)* remote notifications and parse the containing geofence data, and setup those regions for monitoring too.

After a couple of tests in iOS 11 I experienced the following:

- When the app is in foreground/active, while receiving the *(silent)* remote notification, everything works fine: As soon as I receive a remote notification, it gets processed correctly, and the geofences trigger correctly their didEnter/didExit actions.
- When I start this exact same test, but this time with the app in background while receiving the *(silent)* remote notification, the geofences do not work. From what I see from my logs, everything is processed in the exact same way, like when the app would run in active state. Except the didEnter/didExit actions are never triggered...

I googled a lot yesterday, but I did not find an explanation for this behavior. My assumption is, that the locationManager somehow acts different, when it comes to setup a region to monitor, while the app is in background-state.

So I wonder if anyone else tried to archieve a similiar geofence scenario, and could me explain why.

thx in advance!

Comment: Tap on the received Push Notification when your app is closed or in Background, then it will work properly.

Comment: a remote notification, or at least in this case (I am not sure if this is general for remote notifications), is not visible when received....aka silent notification. therefore the user cant tap it. the whole thing of this scenario is to perform the fence setup completly in background, with no user interaction involved at any time